# How to Read PDF file which is in subfolder of Resourse folder in webview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, pdf, webview

[image]

I have some PDF formate document in subfolder of Resourse folder in my application.i have try to read these document like this way.here is my code.

```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chapter ofType:@"pdf"];
   NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
   [[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,500) animated:YES];
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, 50.0)"]];
   [webView loadRequest:request];
   [self.view addSubview:webView];
   [webView release];
```

In this code "path" Return Nill value,when i check in console.but when i check the string "chapter" which store my desire pdf document name ,Always it have  one of the pdf document name.In Console when my program is crash it show some thing like this.

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[UIWebView scrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6587d20'
```

Any help will be appriated.

Comment: Here pathForResource is string and check you provided correct string. You provide chapter which is what?? Is it string ?

Comment: chapter is string which contain my desire document name.

Comment: remvove this line [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, 50.0)"]]; remove this line as your setting content offset to 500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you check out your pdf file in your project?

[image]

I test a following code. no problem.

please check your chapter.pdf file in your project. the point is relative path.

**Must be case sensitive. "Chapter" / "chapter" is not equalString.**

```
NSLog(@"path:%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chapter" ofType:@"pdf"]);


console:
    /var/mobile/Applications/72AFA069-D83E-469A-A687-AEAFDB0B4D97/TableViewTest.app/chapter.pdf
```

---

```
NSLog(@"path:%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Chapter" ofType:@"pdf"]);


console:
    (null)
```

---

```
self.myWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame] autorelease];
self.myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.myWebView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.myWebView];
[self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chapter" ofType:@"pdf"]]]];
```

[image]

---

In your project folder name will disappear in a actual iPhone bundle.
You have created a folder called Resource-Common, but eventually disappears in NSBundle.

[image]

See the image below. Both are integrated. folder name in the project is only just visible folder in xcode.

[image]

If you want all pdf file list in NSBundle. try to following code.

```
NSArray *pdfCollection = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: Must be case sensitive. "Chapter" / "chapter" is not equalString.

Comment: Are you post download the code in your link? For now, I do not know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: What is chapter??? Please try the following. NSString *str = @"your pdf file name"; //  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"pdf"];

Comment: "chapter"<<< documents name? where is in? is in NSBundle? or Documents?

Comment: I want to really help you while solved. I re-edited my post. last line check out please.

Comment: check your chapter string exits in pdfCollection array. if not then wrong pdf name returned in your application

Comment: plz @bitmapdata.com send you are email address i wana to share my code with u.thanx for helping me so for.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView's scrollView is a read only property according to Apple's [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html): The scroll view associated with the web view. (read-only).  But you treated it as like a UIScrollView that it was not.  That was the error message.